# Remove selected option from another select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying implement multiple select boxes in a single page. All these select boxes will have the same option values. When I select first option from select box 1, then that option should be removed from remaining select boxes.

```html
<select name="selectBox1" id="selectBox1">
   <option value="option1">option1</option>
   <option value="option2">option2</option>
   <option value="option3">option3</option>
   <option value="option4">option4</option> 
</select>

<select name="selectBox2" id="selectBox2">
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="option3">option3</option>
    <option value="option4">option4</option>    
</select>

<select name="selectBox3" id="selectBox3">
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="option3">option3</option>
    <option value="option4">option4</option>    
</select>
```

How do I do it? I know how to remove or add option if there is only one select box, but for multi select box, I am stuck.

Comment: Just considering myself, I've answered 2 similar questions just this week. Give the site a search.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this : Instead of removing `option`s from the list you can show / hide it, so that if user change selected `option` then same `option` should get restored in rest of the `select` boxes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('select').on('change', function(event ) {
       //restore previously selected value
       var prevValue = $(this).data('previous');
       $('select').not(this).find('option[value="'+prevValue+'"]').show();
       //hide option selected                
       var value = $(this).val();
       //update previously selected data
       $(this).data('previous',value);
       $('select').not(this).find('option[value="'+value+'"]').hide();
   });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w0nnxw75/6/)**

Comment: You solution is good for TWO select boxes, but for three and more, it will unhide options, that were selected in one of other two

Comment: @jevgenig, yeah I corrected the logic, please see updated answer.

Comment: Looks better right now, but have you tried checking if options really gets hided? :) I mean, I can still select same option on your demo, I've updated my answer with "disable/enable" approach

Comment: @jevgenig, yeah those options are getting hided, I have checked in DOM structure using browser DOM inspector. But you approach is good in terms of user experience as user will know which are the options available but disabled. +1 for you!!

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using jquery, code would look like this:

```
$("select").change(function(e){
    var $s = $(e.target);
    $("select").not($s).find("option[value="+$s.val()+"]").remove();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gjhrnb6d/)

**UPDATE** (inspired by Bhushan Kawadkar's answer)

Here is how you can improve it:

```
$("select").change(function(e){
    $("select option").removeAttr('disabled');
    $("select").each(function(i,s){
       $("select").not(s).find("option[value="+$(s).val()+"]").attr('disabled','disabled');
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gjhrnb6d/2/)

Answer (score 1):

here you go: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5vnpoc1p/)

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
    var value=$(this).val();
    $('select').not(this).each(function(){
        $(this).find('option[value='+value+']').remove();
    });
});
```

but keep in mind that this is not how you ask questions in SO, you need to try some code then show what you've tried and ask for help fixing the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to hack your own multiple select box, how about just using a real [multi-select box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-multiple)?

```html
<select name="selectBox1" id="selectBox1" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try if the following code example could work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').on('change', function(event ) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).prop('disabled', false);

    $('select').find('option[value="'+ value +'"]')
     .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
     .hide();
  });
});
```