# Hide selected option from another select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

*Edit, yes I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137309/remove-selected-option-from-another-select-box) question but that answer is not completely working for my case*

**I'm looking for a solution for this case**

When a user selects an option from one select box the option should be *hidden* for the other select boxes.
When a selected option changes or is removed (select a blank option) the previously selected option should become available again to the other select boxes.

**The problem with my current code:**

When an option changes, the previous option is not "released" to the other select boxes so they can not use it again until the page reloads.
Basically, results in previously selected options are dissapearing from other select boxes.

I included a fiddle so you can see it for youself.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // this "initializes the boxes"
  $('.update-select').each(function(box) {

    var value = $('.update-select')[box].value;

    if (value) {

      $('.update-select').not(this).find('option[value="' + value + '"]').hide();
    }
  });

  // this is called every time a select box changes
  $('.update-select').on('change', function(event) {

    var prevValue = $(this).data('previous');
    $('.update-select').not(this).find('option[value="' + prevValue + '"]').show();
    var value = $(this).val();

    if (value) {

      $(this).data('previous', value);
      console.log($(this).data('previous', value));
      $('.update-select').not(this).find('option[value="' + value + '"]').hide();
    }

  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  float: right;
}

body div {
  margin: 20px;
}

select {
  border: 2px solid #78909c;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none
}

select:focus {
  border: 2px solid #ff9800;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3>stock 1</h3>
  <select name="tracker[stockitems][0]" class="update-select">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1" selected>tracker 1</option>
    <option value="3">tracker 2</option>
    <option value="4">test tracker1</option>
    <option value="6">another tracker</option>
    <option value="9">the last tracker</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <h3>stock 2</h3>
  <select name="tracker[stockitems][1]" class="update-select">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">tracker 1</option>
    <option value="3" selected>tracker 2</option>
    <option value="4">test tracker1</option>
    <option value="6">another tracker</option>
    <option value="9">the last tracker</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <h3>stock 3</h3>
  <select name="tracker[stockitems][2]" class="update-select">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">tracker 1</option>
    <option value="3">tracker 2</option>
    <option value="4">test tracker1</option>
    <option value="6">another tracker</option>
    <option value="9">the last tracker</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: @ShaktiPhartiyal 
When a user selects an option from one select box the option should be hidden for the other select boxes.
When a selected option changes or is removed (select a blank option) the previously selected option should become available again to the other select boxes.

Comment: It's too simple, just show all the options and then reinitialize them using your current code. Check my answer for update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's as simple as this. Just `.show()` all the `option`'s and reinitialize the `select`'s using your previous code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function intializeSelect() {
    // this "initializes the boxes"
    $('.update-select').each(function(box) {
      var value = $('.update-select')[box].value;
      if (value) {
        $('.update-select').not(this).find('option[value="' + value + '"]').hide();
      }
    });
  };

  intializeSelect();

  // this is called every time a select box changes
  $('.update-select').on('change', function(event) {
    $('.update-select').find('option').show();
    intializeSelect();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  float: right;
}

body div {
  margin: 20px;
}

select {
  border: 2px solid #78909c;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none
}

select:focus {
  border: 2px solid #ff9800;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3>stock 1</h3>
  <select name="tracker[stockitems][0]" class="update-select">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1" selected>tracker 1</option>
    <option value="3">tracker 2</option>
    <option value="4">test tracker1</option>
    <option value="6">another tracker</option>
    <option value="9">the last tracker</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <h3>stock 2</h3>
  <select name="tracker[stockitems][1]" class="update-select">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">tracker 1</option>
    <option value="3" selected>tracker 2</option>
    <option value="4">test tracker1</option>
    <option value="6">another tracker</option>
    <option value="9">the last tracker</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <h3>stock 3</h3>
  <select name="tracker[stockitems][2]" class="update-select">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">tracker 1</option>
    <option value="3">tracker 2</option>
    <option value="4">test tracker1</option>
    <option value="6">another tracker</option>
    <option value="9">the last tracker</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm almost, but you got me in the right direction. If you call `intializeSelect()` right after the document ready it works for me. Can you edit you answer to this?

Comment: @TimBorowy - Oh my bad, I missed to add that. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Great, I accepted your answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome, Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '.update-select', function(e) {
        $('option').show();

        var selectedOptionsGlobal = [];

        $.each($('.update-select'), function(key, select) {
            var selectedOptionValue = $(select).val();

            if (selectedOptionValue !== "") {
                selectedOptionsGlobal.push(selectedOptionValue);
            }
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < selectedOptionsGlobal.length; i++) {
            $('option[value="'+selectedOptionsGlobal[i]+'"]').hide();
        }
    });
});
```