# How can I put validation in react, that if I have choose an option from a drop down, then that option will be disable in the other drop down menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation

I am designing a form in react in which I have two categories of dropdown. one is named as "What include" and the other is "What is not include". Now I want that if the user to select any option from the menu of "What Include", then that option(item) will be disabled in the other drop-down named "What not Include".

Here is the code for handle change and UI:

```
const [personwhatIncludeItems, setPersonwhatIncludeItems] = React.useState(
    []
  );
  const [personnotIncludeItems, setPersonnotIncludeItems] = React.useState([]);

  const handlenotIncludeItemsChange = (event) => {
    const {
      target: { value },
    } = event;
    setPersonnotIncludeItems(
      // On autofill we get a stringified value.
      typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value
    );
  };
  

  const handlewhatIncludeItemsChange = (event) => {
    const {
      target: { value },
    } = event;
    setPersonwhatIncludeItems(
      // On autofill we get a stringified value.
      typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value
    );
  };
    <div className="col-6 mt-2 mb-2">
                        <FormControl fullWidth>
                          <InputLabel id="multiple-include-label">
                            {" "}
                            Includes
                          </InputLabel>
                          <Select
                            labelId="whatInclude-multiple-checkbox-label"
                            id="whatInclude-multiple-checkbox"
                            multiple
                            value={personwhatIncludeItems}
                            onChange={handlewhatIncludeItemsChange}
                            input={<OutlinedInput label="Tag" />}
                            renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(", ")}
                            MenuProps={MenuProps}
                          >
                            {whatIncludeArr.map((whatIncludeItems) => (
                              <MenuItem
                                key={whatIncludeItems}
                                value={whatIncludeItems}
                              >
                                <Checkbox
                                  checked={
                                    personwhatIncludeItems.indexOf(
                                      whatIncludeItems
                                    ) > -1
                                  }
                                />
                                <ListItemText primary={whatIncludeItems} />
                              </MenuItem>
                            ))}
                          </Select>
                        </FormControl>
                      </div>
                      <div className="col-6 mt-2 mb-2">
                        <FormControl fullWidth>
                          <InputLabel id="multiple-not-include-label">
                            {" "}
                            Not Includes
                          </InputLabel>
                          <Select
                            labelId="whatnotInclude-multiple-checkbox-label"
                            id="whatnotInclude-multiple-checkbox"
                            multiple
                            value={personnotIncludeItems}
                            onChange={handlenotIncludeItemsChange}
                            input={<OutlinedInput label="Not Include" />}
                            renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(", ")}
                            MenuProps={MenuProps}
                          >
                            {WhatNotIncludeArr.map((notIncludeItems) => (
                              <MenuItem
                                key={notIncludeItems}
                                value={notIncludeItems}
                              >
                                <Checkbox
                                  checked={
                                    personnotIncludeItems.indexOf(notIncludeItems) >
                                    -1
                                  }
                                />
                                <ListItemText primary={notIncludeItems} />
                              </MenuItem>
                            ))}
                          </Select>
                        </FormControl>
                      </div>
```

Comment: You can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74846625/modifying-select-values-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript/74846804#74846804

Comment: @SubramonianInian not working .I've added .filter((x) => x.value !== personnotIncludeItems) before the map function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand the logic, but if the goal is to disable the options if selected else where, perhaps consider to add conditional `disabled` for each mapped option (*if the other selected state already has the value, disable the option*), perhaps such as:

Minimized demo of below example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kc1pkg?file=src/App.js)

Although not tagged as it, the posted code looks like MUI so the example will use MUI components, but otherwise the approach could still work with other libraries provided that a `disabled` property is supported.

*"What Include"* select:

```
  <div className="col-6 mt-2 mb-2">
    <FormControl fullWidth>
      <InputLabel id="multiple-include-label"> Includes</InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="whatInclude-multiple-checkbox-label"
        id="whatInclude-multiple-checkbox"
        multiple
        value={personwhatIncludeItems}
        onChange={handlewhatIncludeItemsChange}
        input={<OutlinedInput label="Tag" />}
        renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(", ")}
        MenuProps={MenuProps}
      >
        {whatIncludeArr.map((whatIncludeItems) => (
          <MenuItem
            key={whatIncludeItems}
            value={whatIncludeItems}
            //  Added disable condition here
            disabled={personnotIncludeItems.includes(whatIncludeItems)}
          >
            <Checkbox
              checked={personwhatIncludeItems.indexOf(whatIncludeItems) > -1}
              //  Added disable condition here
              disabled={personnotIncludeItems.includes(whatIncludeItems)}
            />
            <ListItemText primary={whatIncludeItems} />
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  </div>
```

*"What is not include"* select:

```
  <div className="col-6 mt-2 mb-2">
    <FormControl fullWidth>
      <InputLabel id="multiple-not-include-label"> Not Includes</InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="whatnotInclude-multiple-checkbox-label"
        id="whatnotInclude-multiple-checkbox"
        multiple
        value={personnotIncludeItems}
        onChange={handlenotIncludeItemsChange}
        input={<OutlinedInput label="Not Include" />}
        renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(", ")}
        MenuProps={MenuProps}
      >
        {WhatNotIncludeArr.map((notIncludeItems) => (
          <MenuItem
            key={notIncludeItems}
            value={notIncludeItems}
            //  Added disable condition here
            disabled={personwhatIncludeItems.includes(notIncludeItems)}
          >
            <Checkbox
              checked={personnotIncludeItems.indexOf(notIncludeItems) > -1}
              //  Added disable condition here
              disabled={personwhatIncludeItems.includes(notIncludeItems)}
            />
            <ListItemText primary={notIncludeItems} />
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  </div>
```